# Presto Unnest varchar array field with {}

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, unnest

I have a column with inconsistent data format, some of them are a list of array [], some of them are JSON_like objects {}

| id | prices |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [100,100,110] |
| 2 | {200,210,190} |

```
create table test(id integer, prices varchar(255));
insert into test 
values
(1,'[100,100,110]'),
(2,'{200,210,190}');
```

When I tried to unnest, my query works fine for the first row, but it fails on the second row.  Is there a way I can convert the {} to a list of array []?

This is my query:

```
select id,prices,price from test 
cross join UNNEST(cast(json_parse(prices) as array<varchar>)) as t (price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#id0) and then parse the data into array:

```sql
select json_parse(replace(replace('{200,210,190}', '}', ']'), '{', '['))
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [200,210,190] |

Comment: Thanks, I used a regexp_replace to get rid of curly brackets